# Making a fixed header appear persistent

Tags: jquery, html, css, frontend

I built a photography website for a client of myne here ->

http://lorenzo.dentasignclients.com

As you can see the design has a fixed header that's consistent on all the pages.

Right now, when you browse through pages, the header logo, alongside the header background image flashes slightly.

Without transforming the site into Ajax, is there a way to make it appear as though the header is being persistent as the user moves through pages? I think the effect would be cool, but isn't necessarily turning all post requests into ajax.

Comment: I dont think its possible without Ajax as far as I know. Its possible only with jQuery in one page (one file and th loading specific images etc), maybe with hash change(if not using ajax) as I did with my portfolio page (not yetfinished) -> [MY PAGE](http://revelier.home.pl/SzymonDz/)  .Btw, good looking website at least one designer doing clean beautiful website, you are 1% of designers with taste, keep goin :)

Comment: Szymon, that felt amazing to hear. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the header actually was appearing persistent, it's just that when loading new pages, while waiting for the background image to load, it was plain white. Because of that, it appeared as though the header needed more time to load. By changing the background color to something more grayish, I was able to make it look a bit better.

Though as Szymon pointed out, definitely ajax would have been the best option. Okay, gotta get learning!